# how to loop through an array with nested objects using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

if I have an array like this:

```
var msg = [ {name: ["a1", "a2"], value: "this is A"},
            {name: ["b1", "b2"], value: "this is B"},
            ...
          ]
```

The array contains global errors messages for client-side form validations. I have managed to pass in faulty inputs (e.g. "a1") and now am wondering how to get the corresponding message out of my ill-constructed array.

**Question**
What would be the best way to loop through this array? for example, if I have "a1" as parameter passed into my function, how do I extract "this is A" as corresponding message?

*inArray* doesn't really help, because I need the corresponding message and not the position of **a1**. I'm also not sure if this is the best way to store my error messages... ideas welcome!

Thanks for help!

Comment: Why can you have multiple `name`s, but only one `value`?

Comment: because some inputs have the same error message. I guess it would be easier if I separated these, woudn't it?

Comment: Posted an answer with the codes and messages split :)

Comment: If you want to have better performance, you need to separate them.

Comment: @Joe: I think I like :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-arrange your data structure:

```
var my_param = 'b1';

// This is an object, so we can have key/value pairs
var error_codes =
{
    'a1': 0,
    'a2': 0,
    'b1': 1,
    'b2': 1
};

// This is an array because we only need values
var error_messages =
[
    'This is A',
    'This is b'
];

alert(error_messages[error_codes[my_param]]);
```

This makes it really easy to set up new error codes and messages, and is extremely easy to understand. The only gotcha is `error_codes[my_param]` - it's an object, but we can't do `error_codes.my_param` because it'll look for the element called 'my_param', so using array notation, we can look up the object key.

The only other potential trap is making sure you don't have any trailing commas:

```
var error_codes = { 'a1': 1, }; // NO!
```

Also knows as the [trailing comma of death](http://www.enterprisedojo.com/2010/12/19/beware-the-trailing-comma-of-death/)!

Comment: VERY NICE! Thanks everybody, but I like this best!

Answer (score 1):

This would be how I'd do it

```
var myMsg = findMsg('a1')


function findMsg(msgType){
  msg.forEach(function(obj){
    if(inArray(msgType, obj.name) !== -1){
      return obj.value
    }
  })
}

function inArray(key, obj){
 return obj.join().indexOf(key)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) is the jQuery way for taking action on each element of an array or each enumerable property of an object.

```
var value;
$.each(msg, function (i, el) {
  if (el.name.indexOf(name) >= 0) {
    value = el.value;
    return false;  // Stops iteration.
  }
});
```

If `name` is `"a1"` then after running the above, `value === "this is A"`.

Comment: What's wrong with the JS `for ... in` for iterating over JS objects? :P Easy enough, and doesn't have the jQ overhead

Comment: It's fine for an `Object` but certainly not fine for an `Array` (where `for(var i = 0; i < foo.length; ++ i)` is preferred.)  Using `for .. in` with an `Array` would include properties in `Array.prototype`.

Answer (score 0):

Nice and simple:

```
var getMessage = function (name)
{
    var msg = [ ... ];

    for(var i = 0; i < msg.length; ++ i)
        if (msg [i].name.indexOf (name) != -1)
            return msg [i].value;
}
```

Returns either the corresponding message or `undefined` if the name wasn't found.

You may need a shim for `indexOf` depending on which browsers you want to support:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf